# Sign In With Google button responsive design

Tags: google-signin

Is there any way to make the new "Sign In With Google" button responsive?  Specifically, vary the width based on the width of the containing element?  I'd really just like to set the width to 100%.

I'm aware I can set the data-width attribute but this sets it to an explicit width and doesn't update if you change it after the initial script load - you have to reload the whole script to resize the width.

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround, and it worked for me. As I needed the button to have 100% width in mobile devices.

If you have another element on the screen that behaves the same way you need (like having its width 100%), you can select it using a querySelector, and get its width `element.clientWidth`, after this you can pass the width to the [renderButton](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton) function provided by google.

But this solution is not valid if you would like the button to change its size on resizing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution but it works for us.  We're using Twitter Bootstrap.

The new JavaScript library has a [renderButton](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton) method. You can therefore render the button multiple times on one page passing different widths to each button using something like this (400 is the max width allowed by the library)

```
private renderAllGoogleSignInButtons(): void {
  this.renderGoogleSignInButton(document.getElementById('google-signin-xs'), 400);
  this.renderGoogleSignInButton(document.getElementById('google-signin-sm'), 280);
  this.renderGoogleSignInButton(document.getElementById('google-signin-md'), 372);
  this.renderGoogleSignInButton(document.getElementById('google-signin-lg'), 400);
  this.renderGoogleSignInButton(document.getElementById('google-signin-xl'), 400);
}

private renderGoogleSignInButton(element: HTMLElement, width: number){
  const options {
    type: 'standard',
    ....
    width: width
  };

  google.accounts.id.renderButton(element, options);
}
```

We then use the display classes from bootstrap to hide/show each button depending on the size.

```
    <div class="mx-auto" style="max-width: 400px">
      <div class="d-none-sm d-none-md d-none-lg d-none-xl">
        <div id="google-signin-xs"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-none-md d-none-lg d-none-xl">
        <div id="google-signin-sm"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-none-sm d-none-lg d-none-xl">
        <div id="google-signin-md"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-none-sm d-none-md d-none-xl">
        <div id="google-signin-lg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-none-sm d-none-md d-none-lg">
        <div id="google-signin-xl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

We use a wrapper container with mx-auto and a max-width to center the buttons but you don't have to do this.

Our actual implementation is slightly different than the above as we're using Angular and the button is a component but you can get the idea from the above.

The only drawback with this method is that the "personalized button" doesn't seem to display for all rendered buttons but it doesn't seem to affect their functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the new [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview).

You could try listening for a resize in the window using the [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event), then re-render the Google Sign In button on change. The assumption here is that the container will respond to match the window size:

```
addEventListener('resize', (event) => {});

onresize = (event) => {
  const element = document.getElementById('someContainer');
  if (element) {
    renderGoogleButton(document.getElementById('googleButton'), element.offsetWidth); // adjust to whatever proportion of the "container" you like
  }
}

renderGoogleButton(element, width) {
  const options = {
    type: 'outline',
    width: width
  }
  google.accounts.id.renderButton(element, options);
}
```

I've also had better results when the button is centered, not left aligned. The following in Bootstrap:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div id="googleButton"></div>
</div>
```

NB: The max width for the Google button as of the time of writing is 400px, so bear that value in mind as the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I used transform: scale like this in the CSS:

```
.sign_in_btn_wrapper {
     transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
     float: left;
     margin-left: 20vmin;
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then, instead of wrapping it as I intended, I found that it was fine to just add the class directly to the goog div:

```
<div class="g_id_signin sign_in_btn_wrapper"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left"
     data-width="250">
</div>
```

By fiddling with combinations of data-size and data-width, along with the scaling factors, I was able to make it the size I wanted.  You can use CSS media queries to adjust the 'transform: scale' values so that it is 'Responsive' to the display size of the user's device.  You could also use other trickier methods by having JS tweak variables in your CSS that are then used to set the scaling factors.

Good luck.  You'd think it'd be in the interest of these big 'sign in with' providers to get together a coordinating working group to make it easier for web site developers to make all the sign-in buttons the same damn size -- you know they'd rather not have their button come out smaller, and pages look better when things are uniform.  And what's with only having dimensions in pixels?  At least give us vw, vh, and my favorite: vmin.  (Using vmin to set things like font size means you can often skip more tedious RWD contortions and call it good enough.) </end_rant>